# java - Send POST xml to SOAP web service not working

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I'm trying to send a simple XML through a java application to this SOAP webservice:
http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?op=GetGeoIP

My code is currently like this:

```
        String url = "http://www.webservicex.net"; 
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        post.setHeader("Host", "www.webservicex.net");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
        post.setHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIP");

        String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n" + 
                "  <soap:Body>\r\n" + 
                "    <GetGeoIP xmlns=\"http://www.webservicex.net/\">\r\n" + 
                "      <IPAddress>50.207.31.216</IPAddress>\r\n" + 
                "    </GetGeoIP>\r\n" + 
                "  </soap:Body>\r\n" + 
                "</soap:Envelope>";

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlString));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
                                            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(result.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm not using the WSLD generated classes, as you can see I'm trying to send the XML directly. But I can't seem to get the right response this way, it only returns 302 or 400.

I'm kind of a beginner with using SOAP services, and I don't really know if I'm doing all of this the right way.

Can anyone help me on this?

---

**UPDATE**

When I try to make the request through Advanced Rest Client:

```
Host: www.webservicex.net
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 362
SOAPAction: http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIP
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetGeoIP xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">
      <IPAddress>string</IPAddress>
    </GetGeoIP>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I get: *HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly change the url from "http://www.webservicex.net" to "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx".

Secondly, adding the string as string entity solves the problem.

```
 StringEntity  xmlString = new StringEntity( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n" +
                "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n" +
                "  <soap:Body>\r\n" +
                "    <GetGeoIP xmlns=\"http://www.webservicex.net/\">\r\n" +
                "      <IPAddress>50.207.31.216</IPAddress>\r\n" +
                "    </GetGeoIP>\r\n" +
                "  </soap:Body>\r\n" +
                "</soap:Envelope>");
        post.setEntity(xmlString);
```

Comment: I tried changing the URL and still get the same error. Maybe some of the headers are wrong?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Cache-Control: private, Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8, Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0, X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, Date: Sun, 18 Feb 2018 16:30:40 GMT, Content-Length: 0]

Comment: and when I try to send through Advanced Rest Client I get HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name

Comment: Try to use rest assured "http://rest-assured.io/". It much easier to use.

Comment: I'll take a look into it. Is it a java library?